# Hash to Array converting

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I need this Hash

```
{"peter" => ["apple", "orange", "mango"], "sandra" => ["flowers", "bike"]}
```

convert to this Array:

```
[["peter", "apple"], ["peter", "orange"], ["peter", "mango"], ["sandra", "flowers"], ["sandra", "bike"]]
```

Now I have got this solution

```
my_hash.inject([]){|ar, (k,v)| ar << v.map{|c| [k,c]}}.flatten(1)
```

But I believe here is more elegant solution with those `zip` or `transpose` magick :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right to be suspicious about `Enumerable#inject` solutions. In Ruby, `inject/reduce` is somewhat abused, we must be careful and choose the right abstraction (map, select, zip, flatten...) if they fit the problem at hand. In this case:

```
h = {"peter" => ["apple", "orange", "mango"], "sandra" => ["flowers", "bike"]}
h.map { |k, vs| vs.map { |v| [k, v] } }.flatten(1)
#=> [["peter", "apple"], ["peter", "orange"], ["peter", "mango"], ["sandra", "flowers"], ["sandra", "bike"]]
```

But if you want to use `Enumerable#zip` don't let anyone stop you ;-)

```
h.map { |k, vs| [k].cycle(vs.size).zip(vs) }.flatten(1)
```

And as @steenslag says, also:

```
h.map { |k, vs| [k].product(vs) }.flatten(1)
```

So at the end we can write:

```
h.flat_map { |k, vs| [k].product(vs) }
```

Comment: tokland, that's cheating! He asked for `zip`or `transpose` magick! **EDIT:** Sorry, you edited it 23 seconds before I wrote this comment.

Comment: @serabe, I think fl00r was just mentioning some functional constructions, not that he specifically wanted a zip-based solution. My second snippet is just for fun, the first is probably more clear.

Comment: @Serabe, tokland is right, I was asking for any more elegant solution :)

Comment: [k].product(vs) in stead of [k].cycle(vs.size).zip(vs) ?

Comment: @steenslag: no zip in there, but yes, good idea to use product, added.

Comment: @Serabe I guess you don't remember me from Conferencia Rails

Comment: @Serabe, this last comment was for me? I didn't remember your name, but I do remember reviewing my presentation with a mathematician at Conferencia Rails, is that you?

Comment: @Serabe: hi Sergio, it was pretty sure it was you! yeah, I see know the profile. I didn't know you were in SO, glad to meet you here.

Answer (score 2):

```
h.inject([]){|a,(k,vs)| a+vs.map {|v| [k,v]}}
```

You could also use this version

```
h.inject([]){|a,(k,vs)| a+=vs.map {|v| [k,v]}}
```

Which is most efficient because it use the same list rather than creating a new one at each iteration. However it feels wrong (for me) to use `inject` and modify a variable in place. An `each` version would do the same.

```
a = []; h.each {|k,vs| a+=vs.map {|v| [k,v]}}
```

It's slightly shorter and as expressive.

Answer (score 1):

With `zip`

```
hash.inject([]){ |ar, (k,v)| ar << ([k]*v.size).zip(v) }
```

A plausible solution using `transpose` too:

```
[
  hash.keys.map{|k| [k]*hash[k].size }.flatten,
  hash.keys.map{|k| hash[k] }.flatten
].transpose
```

Take into account that:

1. `hash.keys` should return the keys in the same order in both cases, so don't use it in other language unless you are sure of this.
2. I would go with the first option.